# How to prevent user to delete files in "Related Items" field on Wokflow Tasks - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I'm struggling in order to try to prevent users to delete files in "**Related Items**" field on Workflow Tasks.

[image]

As you can see above, there is a field called "Doc. Review (Original)" then you see the options "**Remove**" and "**ADD RELATED ITEM**".

The question is: how can I prevent the users to use both options?

**What I have already tried:**

- Disable "Delete" options in "Permission Level";
- ReadOnly option changed to "True" in Sharepoint Manager 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Under the List Content Types section click on Task content type.
Hide the Related Items column. By default it would be optional

Else use share point designer:
search for "Related" in Code view, and then set the  tag to . This will hide the “Related list item” in task form.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear before. What I want is that the user has access to related items field but not being able to delete or add new items.

Answer (score 0):

Open the SharePoint Workflow form that you want to hide the REMOVE and ADD RELATED ITEMS from. Then go to the browser's developer tool/page inspector (depending on which browser you are using maybe different) and inspect the two items to find their ID.

Once you have the IDs go back to the SharePoint Workflow form that you want to hide the two items. Click on the gear icon in the upper right corner and click ADD A WEB PART and go to MEDIA AND CONTENT under the Categories section then add the SCRIPT EDITOR.

Once the SCRIPT EDITOR is added click EDIT SNIPPET and try the following:

If the ID stay the same:

`<style type="text/css">
      #ID_FOR_THE_ADD_RELATED_ITEM { display: none !important; }
      #ID_FOR_THE_REMOVE_ITEM  { display: none !important; }
</style>`

If the ID changes (use wilcards $="ID ends with" *="ID contains specific word/characters" ^="ID starts with"; in this example the IDs end with "_ri_add_related_items" and "_ri_item_remove"):

`<style type="text/css">
      [id$='_ri_add_related_items'] { display: none !important; }
      [id$='_ri_item_remove'] { display: none !important; }
</style>`

Click INSERT > STOP EDITING (You may have to click on the PAGE icon to drop down to see it)

This worked for me hopefully it works for you.